# initialize const member by initializer with output param

Tags: c++, mpi

There is a function which gives back return value by using pointer to output: [`MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_Comm comm, int *rank)`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man3/MPI_Comm_rank.3.php)

There is a class which uses it

```
struct MyRank
{
  int rank;
  MyRank(MPI_Comm comm) {
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
  }
}
```

I'd like to elegantly (e.g. by some lambda or other one-liner) make `rank` to be const field and initialize it on initializer list.

I may write a helper function and use it:

```
int getRank(MPI_Comm comm) {
  int rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);  
  return rank;
}

struct MyRank
{
  int const rank;
  MyRank(MPI_Comm comm) : rank(getRank(comm)) {}
}
```

But it is 5 lines more. Maybe there is shorter way, e.g by using lambdas. Any ideas?

Comment: What is elegant is rather opinion-based. Imho your solution is very elegant. And minimizing number of lines of code can result in the most unreadable often

Comment: different approach would be to make `rank` private and non-const. `const` members are actually rather nasty

Answer (score 4):

You might use lambda directly invoked.

```
struct MyRank
{
  int const rank;
  MyRank(MPI_Comm comm) : rank([](MPI_Comm comm) {
      int rank;
      MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);  
      return rank;
    }(comm))
  {}
};
```

Not sure it is more readable though.